# rxObservable from coroutines-rx2 lib doesn't work with Observables.combineLatest

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to gradually convert an android code base from RxJava2 to Kotlin coroutines. We are using `UseCases` and `Repositories`. I've converted one of the repository methods returning `Observable` to be a `suspend` function.

Now, there was a `UseCase` using `Observables.combineLatest` to combine 2 repository `Observables`, one of which is the one I converted to be `suspend`.

In order to still use that `UseCase` function as is, I converted the `suspend` function to be an `observable` using `kotlinx-coroutines-rx2` that provides interop between rxjava and coroutines. I'm using [this](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/kotlinx.coroutines.rx2/rx-observable.html) method specifically.

This is how the code looks:

```
override fun execute(): Observable<GetFollowersResult> {
    return Observables.combineLatest(
        // This suspend function is not getting called
        rxObservable<ProfilesPageDomainModel>(Dispatchers.IO) { profileRepository.getFollowers() },
        profileRepository.getProfile().toObservable()
    ) { followers, profile ->
        // mapping code
    }.subscribeOn(threadExecutor)
        .map<GetFollowersResult> { page ->
            // result
        }
        .onErrorReturn { throwable ->
            // error
        }
        .observeOn(postExecutionThread)
        .startWith(GetFollowersResult.InFlight)
}
```

But even when the observable returned by `combineLatest` is subscribed, the suspend function inside `rxObservable` doesn't get called.

Am i missing something? I cannot convert the other method to be `suspend` since that method is used in quite a many places and i still want to keep the `suspend` function since we need to use it in newer `UseCases`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you replace:

```
rxObservable<ProfilesPageDomainModel>(Dispatchers.IO) { profileRepository.getFollowers() }
```

with:

```
rxSingle(Dispatchers.IO) { profileRepository.getFollowers() }.toObservable()
```

as the Rx equivalent of a `suspend` function is either `Single` (when it returns a value) or `Completable` (when it returns `Unit`).

If you check the Javadoc for `rxSingle` and `rxObservable` you will see a subtle difference:

- The `block` function in `rxObservable` returns `Unit`, meaning inside you need to use `send` to emit items.
- The `block` function in `rxSingle` returns `T`, meaning it returns the value of the suspend function called inside.

Comment: Yes! This makes so much sense and it resolved the issue. Thanks for your answer!